# Use iPhone/iPad or Android phone as a Raspberry 2 display?

Tags: display

I'm not talking about VNC but a real time monitor use the HDMI/USB port or other ways.

Comment: VNC, or screencasting is the only way to do this. I am still waiting for Roku type screencast support from Pi, like windows 10 has. Oh... wait Windows IoT has screen cast app... You cant use LCD of any kind since they all use different and custom cables and protocols. This is an old age question answered on the web allot of times already

Answer (score 2):

Without using tools/apps/... like VNC, short answer: no.

Longer answer:

iPad has not support for HDMI in, only out. It has some support for data transfer using the the dock/light connector, but that's it.

Comment: I've seen somy guys in u2b doing such things https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHmpmdZ6pmo and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCWGMM00ZEk , but that seems to be more complicated.

Comment: First link uses VNC. Second one uses custom hardware. Short answer. No, all LCD use custom protocols for image. No support for HDMI